# Angular JS and for loop - [$injector:modulerr]

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Im just trying to set up a simple for loop. I have some HTML and

```
this.users = []
```

Gets filled up with new users from a HTML form.

However I am trying to get the average age of the users from the array but I keep getting the error

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.2/$injector/modulerr?p0=myApp&p1=Error%3A%2…ogleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.3.2%2Fangular.min.js%3A17%3A381)
```

It work's fine if I take out the function

```
this.average()
```

But when I put it in I get the error.

Can anyone spot what's up?

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
var count = 0;


myApp.controller('RegisteredUsers', [function() {

var that = this;

this.current = {'username':this.username,'name':this.name,'password':this.password,'age':this.age,'id':count};

this.users = [];

this.submit = function() {
    that.users.push(angular.copy(that.current));
    that.average();
    console.log(that.users);
};

this.ages = 0;

this.average = function(){
    for (var i = 0; i < that.users.length; i++){
        that.ages = that.ages + that.users.[i].age;
    }
}

}]);
```

Thanks!

Comment: use `that` in place of `this` inside your inner functions (`average` and `submit`). also you should do `var that = this;` otherwise `that` will become global.

Comment: I have edited the code to use that now within those functions but still get the same error for some reason

Comment: click on link and paste the exact error here